# Save value to a file in python

Tags: python

I am using an re.search to find a value in a `.txt` file when I run it I get the value you I need printed on the screen, this is what appears when I run the code.

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1gujcFhb7SyeG9aalFoaXlLd28/edit?usp=drivesdk',
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "url_finder.py", line 5, in <module>
    print re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", line).group() 
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The **https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1gujcFhb7SyeG9aalFoaXlLd28/edit?usp=drivesdk'** is the value I am looking for, all I would like to do is save this value to a seperate text file so I can use it for something else. Is it possible to just stop this error appearing and save the value. Or I would like to set it as a return value, as this script will be running within a script.

Comment: Permission required to access your file, fix something else. Better yet just post it here, external links to code and errors are frowned upon

Answer (score 2):

The error means your `re.search` returned `None`. You're trying to call `match.group()` on a `None` which results in the error.

To work around this try:

```
for line in your_file:
    match = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", line)
    if match is not None:
        return match.group()
```

Now it will return the line..

Or if you want to store it in a variable, you can just use the `match` object and print it once it's found.

```
for line in your_file:
    match = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", line)
    if match is not None:
        break

print match.group()
```

Comment: Thanks, works great, is there anyway I can save the match.group() as a variable i.e. url = the re.search.

Comment: Of course you can save the `match.group()`, or the `match`-object. Or if you simply need to print it, replace the `return` with `print`